# How to get extended attributes thought magento's REST API?

Tags: php, api, magento-1.7

I just start using Magento REST api and after some dancing with OAuth it's working all good. However, I'd like to know how to get the extended attributes of a product. I can get the basic information but none of the extended attributes I created.

I'd prefer to get them all in one go rather than having to create another REST call, product by product, in order to get this additional information. This is way I'd like to modify the default [products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html) api call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it: it seems I created the REST role before creating the new extended attributes, therefore the extended attributes were not assigned to my role! The solution was to go to System > Web Services > REST attributes, and the modify the ACL attributes in order to assign the correct fields to my role. After that the extended attributes appeared on my request without a problem :-)